# Getting code completions from Pyright language server for virtual documents

Tags: vscode-extensions, pyright

I am writing a VS Code extension that uses Pyright as a language server.

Is there a way to get Pyright to provide code completions for [virtual documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents) with non-`file` URI schemes?

I have a [`LanaguageClient`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node) that sends requests to Pyright. Pyright provides the desired code completions when I send it a `file` URI for a document on disk, but it doesn't provide anything when I send it a custom scheme URI (which I have registered a TextDocumentContentProvider for).

Is Pyright perhaps limited to scanning files on disk? Is there any way I can configure it to look for my custom URI scheme?